# How to dispatch redux action only once when react app loaded?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a application where i need to get the users browser lat and long cords. What i did is, I created a inside actions file and dispatch it inside index.js file. i want that dispatch happens only once when app loads for the first time. Whether user can allow or block doesn't mine. it should happen only once. Even when user wantedly refreshes the page.

Steps

1. users visits the site
2. App asks location permission in browser
3. User clicks either allow or block.
4. Permission popup closes.
5. Users wantedly refresh the page, this time that particular function should not fire again.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

try setting the flag in session storage when the application is loaded for the first time. so for the first time session storage wont be set anything, so dispatch it. whenever the user tries to refresh the page. we will be having the value in session storage, then dont dispatch it